# Magento 2 showing different customers name in header

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have shown customer name in header programmatically.But when you login with customer it show other customer name which was logged in past on same web browser on some pages.instead of current customer name in dropdown.

**app/code/[VendorName]/Customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]_Customer::account/customer.phtml
                </argument>
            </action>
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">[VendorName]\Customer\ViewModel\Account\Customer
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>        
        <referenceBlock name="invitation_link_top" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

***app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml***

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

?>
<?php if ($block->customerLoggedIn()) : ?>
    <?php $viewModel = $block->getViewModel(); ?>
    <li class="customer-welcome">
        <span class="customer-name"
              role="link"
              tabindex="0"
              data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
              data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <button type="button"
                    class="action switch"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    data-action="customer-menu-toggle">
                <span><?= $viewModel->getCustomerName() ?></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <?php if ($block->getChildHtml()) :?>
            <div class="customer-menu" data-target="dropdown">
                <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/ViewModel/Account/Customer.php**

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\Customer\ViewModel\Account;

class Customer implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        $customerSession = $this->_customerSession->create();
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $customerSession->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
        }
        return 'Change';
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code which you have try.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Please check i have shared code

Answer (score 0):

Without sharing your code, we can't really help. But it sounds like your private customer data is being cached by FPC or block cache. You should be using knockout so that the private data isn't cached.

For example, you can see how Magento does it in this file.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml